# Accessing subnode in xml

Tags: c#, xml

I have a xml like this

```
<abcd>
    <abcd1>
        <hgjh>txt</hgjh>
        <addedit>true</addedit>
        <Db>txtDB</DB>
        <server>ser</server>
    </abcd1>
    <abcd1>
        <hgjh>txt</hgjh>
        <addedit>false</addedit>
        <Db>txtDB</DB>
        <server>ser</server>
    </abcd1>
</abcd>
```

Now based on addedit flag value if it is true i need to show the db name and server name for any amount of nodes in the xml. I have included two of them for the reference .
Please help me out on this. I tried lot of code in C# not able to reach the required functionality.

Comment: Could you show the code you tried?

Comment: The XML sample provided seems invalid

Comment: So you want to output all nodes that are labeled Db and server?

Comment: I have edited your XML to make it valid. Please, update the XML further if that isn't the structure you have.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you:

```
     XmlDocument Xmlabcd= new XmlDocument();
            Xmlabcd.LoadXml(xml); //xml=your xml
            foreach (XmlNode v in Xmlabcd.ChildNodes)
            {
                if ( v.ChildNodes.Count > 0)
                {
                    bool addedit=false;
                    string DBName=string.Empty;
                    string serverName=string.Empty;
                    foreach (XmlNode child in v.ChildNodes)
                    {
                        if (child.Name.Equals("addedit") )
                        {
                            addedit=child.InnerText=="true"?true:false;
                        }
                        if(child.Name.Equals("Db"))
                        {
                        DBName=child.InnerText;
                        }
                        if(child.Name.Equals("server"))
                        {
                        serverName=child.InnerText;
                        }
                    }

                    //Code to Show Db and server or to add it to one list based on bool addedit(variable) value
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake. Opening "Db" not matching closing "DB".

You can use XPath to select nodes with addedit = true

```
var list = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("abcd1[addedit='true']");

foreach (XmlNode node in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.SelectSingleNode("DB").InnerText);
    Console.WriteLine(node.SelectSingleNode("server").InnerText);
}
```